# Android - Adding multiple views dynamically

Tags: android, layout, dynamic

In my code I'm adding a picture and text below the picture. I have a XML with a RelativeLayout which holds an ImageView and a TextView.
Dynamically I'm inflating this xml layout and adding it to a LinearLayout which is in the root XML. The Problem I'm facing is that if I'm adding more picture that the screen can hold (in width) the last picture gets small. I want to be able to have the same structure and add a new row, for instance i want each row to have maximum 4 picture, how can I achieve this?

Below is my root xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:text="Friends who likes this:"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"/>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my xml layout where i have the imageview and textview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="35dip"
    android:layout_height="35dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
    android:src="@drawable/default_profile_picture"/>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
    android:textSize="9sp"
    android:text="Damian M."/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the Java Code to inflate this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.likes_view, this, true);
    LinearLayout wrapper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setTypeface(tf);
    if(users.isEmpty()){
        text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    RelativeLayout friendsView;
    ImageView image;
    TextView username;
    for(User user : users){
        friendsView = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(ctx, R.layout.likes_view_friends, null);
        image = (ImageView) friendsView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        if(user.getImage() != null){
            image.setImageBitmap(user.getImage());
        }
        username = (TextView) friendsView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        username.setTypeface(tf);
        String firstLetterLastName = user.getLastName().substring(0,1);
        StringBuilder dotLastName = new StringBuilder(firstLetterLastName).append(".");         
        username.setText(user.getFirstName() + " " + dotLastName.toString());
        wrapper.addView(friendsView);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`GridView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html). A tutorial is available at Android Developer Resources [Hello Views](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html)

Comment: I forgot to say, that I'm doing this inside a listview. Can I put the GridView inside the ListView?!

Comment: Yes. You would have to manage 2 adapters, though. One for the `ListView` and one for the `GridView`.

Comment: I see what you're saying. But I want the GridView to act as an item in ListView, so when I scroll down the ListView the pictures should also scroll with the ListView. You're suggestion will lead me to two scrollviews, one for listview and the second for the gridview.

Comment: Ok, I got your problem. If you know the number of items in a row, `GridView` may not really be needed. Moreover, the issue you are having in your layout is because: 1) `RelativeLayout`'s width is set to `fill_parent` (which should be `wrap_content`) and 2) The `ImageView`'s dimensions are hard-coded.  Also, take a look at `layout_weight` attribute of [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#linearlayout)